# Setting up django-nonrel using pip

Tags: django, virtualenv, pip, django-nonrel

I'm trying to install django-nonrel the correct way - **and to be able to reproduce the process**.

I've installed django-nonrel using pip - as following:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel.git
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-dbindexer.git
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-permission-backend-nonrel
pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangoappengine
pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangotoolbox
pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/twanschik/django-autoload
pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/twanschik/nonrel-search/src
```

After installation, I got this req.txt file (pip freeze > req.txt):

```
Django==1.3.1
django-autoload==0.01
django-dbindexer==0.3
djangoappengine==1.0
djangotoolbox==0.9.2
nonrel-search==0.1
permission-backend-nonrel==0.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

But I can't use my req.txt file to get the same stuff.
If I uninstall a package (e.g. django-autoload) and try to get it again using the requirements file

```
(gae-first)bentzy@lama:~/.virtualenvs/gae-first$ pip uninstall django-autoload
Uninstalling django-autoload:
...
Successfully uninstalled django-autoload
(gae-first)bentzy@lama:~/.virtualenvs/gae-first$ pip install -r req.txt 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django==1.3.1       in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r req.txt (line 1))
Downloading/unpacking django-autoload==0.01 (from -r req.txt (line 2))
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-autoload==0.01 (from -r req.txt (line 2))
No distributions at all found for django-autoload==0.01 (from -r req.txt (line 2))
Storing complete log in /home/bentzy/.pip/pip.log
```

Why aren't those packages at pip repository?

It still make sense to use pip to install them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your requirements file does not have enough information.

What `pip` is going  to do when you request it to install `django-autoload`, for instance, is look at PyPI for that package (and scrap some pages after finding the PyPI entry).

If you want to have a requirements file that downloads those packages the same way you did while installing one by one, do the same: tell pip where to find packages.

Create a requirements file like:

```
git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel.git
git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-dbindexer.git
git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-permission-backend-nonrel
hg+https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangoappengine
hg+https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangotoolbox
hg+https://bitbucket.org/twanschik/django-autoload
hg+https://bitbucket.org/twanschik/nonrel-search/src
```

Or if you want to install from specific tag or commit, do:

```
git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel.git@1.3.1#egg=Django
```

Read more about requirements file at http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/logic.html#requirements-file-format

Comment: So the answer is that for some reason the django-nonrel guys didn't add the projects to PyPI. Still, I think it’s worth it to use pip and manually edit the requirements file (with urls - as you described) to keep it simple to reproduce the environment.

Comment: Yes, maybe you should warn them about it.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't really make sense to use pip if you're using GAE, since all the packages you use need to be in your actual GAE project folder.  Packages installed in your system or virtualenv environments won't get uploaded to GAE production servers.

Comment: On the other side - You can simply symlink from your project folder to site-packages and still use pip...    appcfg.py will resolve the symlinks  - My question is other :-)